# LARAVEL - modifing database data before validating

Tags: laravel

I have varchar field in my table and I want to using unique validate but want to remove the whitespace in my table before validate it.

Example :

I have value in database "My Value". And if I send "myvalue" to request data, the validation must be work in this case. How to do it in laravel validation?

Comment: Can you please tell me why do you need that? what is the case? for what purpose?

Comment: User input something like book title, in I must validate by book name

Comment: Can you provide me with full scenario?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know exactly what do you want to do.. DO you mean to do like this?

Go to your model then add this code

```
public function getNameAttribute($value) {
   return str_replace(" ", "", $value);
}
```